# Does uniform boundedness and monotonicity of a sequence of functions imply convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The monotone convergence theorem states for sequences of numbers that a monotonic and bounded sequence converges.

Is there an analog for a sequence of **uniformly-bounded**, monotonic for each $x$, functions $\{f_n(x)\}$? Does this imply uniform convergence, convergence, or nothing?

Comment: Even if you require your functions to be continuous and monotone you can’t conclude anything, as the usual example ${x^n} n \in N$ with $x \in [0,1]$ shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be your sequence of real valued functions. For each $x$ in their domain, the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is monotone and bounded, so is convergent. It follows that the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to the function which maps each $x$ to the limit of $(f_n(x))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

We can't conclude uniform convergence for example if
$$f_n(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
0 & \text{ if }0<x< \frac{1}{n}\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right\}$$